# How to create a custom SSRS user warning?

Tags: reporting-services, messagebox

I have a report that can be VERY expansive - potentially returning hundreds of thousands of rows and taking 15+ minutes to render.  The users have four inputs including two dates indicating the report range and two filters that default to (All).  What I'd like to do is throw up a warning to the user if they try to run the report without selecting a single entity from either of the two filters, or if the user attempts to bring up more than one week's worth of data at a time.

Is there any kind of checking I can do at runtime in the report (short of coding it in the procedure) to warn the user that they are about to get more data than they can handle?

Comment: You won't be able to do anything at runtime like you're asking, not without writing your own interface.  What about making the report run immediately with its default parameters, but rather than display report content, display a warning to the user about how to use the report?  Then just hide the warning when the parameters are changed for a real execution.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Hidden Parameter e.g. Accept_Run_Time_Warnings, with Static values e.g. Yes or No. The Default value would be set by an expression, based on the prior Parameters and your criteria e.g. entities selected, date ranges etc. If those conditions are met, Default = No, otherwise Default = Yes.

Then I would add a textbox to the top of the report body with the warning text to show the users, finishing with something like "Click here to continue with these parameters".  This textbox would be hidden if Accept_Run_Time_Warnings = Yes.  This textbox would have an Action to run the same report, passing the same paramters, but with the Accept_Run_Time_Warnings = Yes.

I would hide all other report body tables charts etc if Accept_Run_Time_Warnings = No.

I would edit the parameters for the main datasets to test Accept_Run_Time_Warnings - if No then they can pass non-existent values (to speed the dataset execution), e.g.

`=Iif ( Parameters!Accept_Run_Time_Warnings.Value = "No" , "DUMMMY" , Parameters!Customer.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas.  We decided instead to break the report into two reports and removed the "All" option from either one of the two selection drop-downs on each report.  The titles on the individual reports give a clue to the user about which one to use and clue them into the need for a selection.